# ASP.NET ImageButton OnClick Event return 406

Tags: asp.net, webforms, http-status-code-406

In Advance, I'sorry. cause i'm not good at English. 
Please Read All and Answer this Problem. 
I have an ASP.NET ImageButton with an OnClick Property. On the CodeFile, There is Web API called `'PreView_Click'`. When users Select a file want to upload and click the `Button`, It returns

> 406 Not Acceptable. The Server is IIS7. MIME Type Of Server already
>   is well Adapted. Ex) .xls, .xlsx

Here is my code. Thanks in Advance!

and aspx.cs Code

```
protected void PreView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileNames = (string)ViewState["FileName"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileNames))
    {
        DataTable xlsDT = XLSReader(URL + "/" + FileNames);
        GridView1.DataSource = xlsDT;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        if (ErrCnt == 0)
        {
            Save_File.Visible = true;
            saveTxt.InnerText = xlsDT.Rows.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because the MIME type that is specified in the Accept header of the client request does not match the MIME type that is specified for the requested content file name extension on the server.

Please find the documentation from Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942050/error-message-when-you-visit-a-web-site-that-is-hosted-on-a-server-tha

To resolve this problem, make sure that the Accept header of the client request matches the MIME type that is specified for the requested content file name extension on the server. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Start IIS Manager. To do this, click **Start**, click **Run**, type inetmgr.exe, and then click **OK**.
2. In IIS Manager, expand the server name, expand **Web sites**, and then click the Web site that you want to modify.
3. In Features View, double-click **MIME Types**.
4. Double-click the MIME type that you want to modify.
5. In the **Edit MIME type** dialog box, type the appropriate **MIME type** for the content file name extension in the MIME Type box.

**Note** You can also set the MIME type of the content file name extension to `*/*` to accept any MIME type.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but MIME types of Server has no problem. I have no idea. Is there any other solution?